# VBA Macro to Export Macros

Tags: vba, excel

I want to write a macro that exports macros that are present in the VBA Editor Project View since *it is not possible to export multiple files*!

The reason why I want to do this is because I need the `.bas` and `.cls` files to create a doxygen documentation out of them.

If anyone knows an easier solution please let me know. Otherwise: How can I export all VBA Code Files at once from a project?

Best regards and thank you!

Comment: `if (typeof(T) == typeof(UInt16))`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, needless to say, whichever code "touches your code" must be **trusted**.

Yes, it is possible and you can use the VBProject and VBComponent to achieve it. Please take a look [here](http://www.experts-exchange.com/Software/Office_Productivity/Office_Suites/MS_Office/Excel/A_1457-Automate-Exporting-all-Components-in-an-Excel-Project.html) and [here](http://www.ozgrid.com/forum/showthread.php?t=69333). Those link explain quite well how to do what you asked.

Comment: @StefanFalk Please add your answer (do not edit mine) if you think it'd do good.

Comment: My edit was just code that did what you suggested for people who come here after us

Comment: Then please if you can add your answer below mine, you will do good for the community :)

Answer (score 0):

Working example, exports `.bas`, .`cls` and `.frm` modules:

```
Option Explicit

Public Sub MakeDoxy()

    Dim rootDir As String
    Dim sourceDir As String

    rootDir = GetFolder("C:\") & "\"
    sourceDir = rootDir & "source\"

    If Dir(rootDir, vbDirectory) = "" Then
        MkDir rootDir
    End If

    If Dir(sourceDir, vbDirectory) = "" Then
        MkDir sourceDir
    End If

    ExportVBAModules (sourceDir)

End Sub

Private Sub ExportVBAModules(ByVal sourceDir As String)

    Dim objVBComp As VBComponent
    Dim objVBProj As VBProject
    Dim ext As String

    Set objVBProj = ThisWorkbook.VBProject

    For Each objVBComp In objVBProj.VBComponents

        ' We don't export THIS module
        If objVBComp.Name = "MakeDoxygen" Then GoTo Skip

        If Dir(sourceDir & objVBComp.Name, vbDirectory) = "" Then
            MkDir sourceDir & objVBComp.Name
        End If

        Select Case objVBComp.Type
            Case vbext_ct_ClassModule: ext = ".cls"
            Case vbext_ct_Document: GoTo Skip
            Case vbext_ct_StdModule: ext = ".bas"
            Case vbext_ct_MSForm: ext = ".frm"
            Case Else: GoTo Skip
        End Select

        objVBComp.Export sourceDir & objVBComp.Name & "\" & objVBComp.Name & ext
Skip:
    Next

End Sub


Private Function GetFolder(strPath As String) As String

    Dim fldr As FileDialog
    Dim sItem As String
    Set fldr = Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFolderPicker)

    With fldr
        .Title = "Select ''VBADoxy'' Root Folder"
        .AllowMultiSelect = False
        .InitialFileName = strPath
        If .Show <> -1 Then GoTo NextCode
        sItem = .SelectedItems(1)
    End With

NextCode:
    GetFolder = sItem
    Set fldr = Nothing

End Function
```